# Sharepoint 2013: Design workflow: Send Email

Tags: email, sharepoint

I'm beginning learning how to to design some basic workflow with sharepoint designer 2013.

I have a workflow that:

- when a property is verified for a list item
- it is dupplicated in another custom list.

I would like to send a custom email after the dupplication.
I added a send email action and i used some lookup fields in the subject and the body.

In the designer i have for exemple the string: [%CurrentItem : Title%] in the body and the subject field.

But when i receive the email. The string  [%CurrentItem : Title%] is not translated in the mail body.
whereas the same string is correctly replaced by "My Tile" in the subject field.

Is there something special to do to use lookup variable in the emailBody?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to SharePoint Designer 2013 version.
My SharePoint Designer 2013 was in french version and the SharePoint Online 2013 was in english version. 
Some parameters were not recognized in the body generation.